# Vimeo API GET direct link to file returns unusable link

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Sometimes, the Vimeo API returns a direct link (files->link_secure) that is unusable (error code 403 - unauthorized access)

Here is what the unusable url looks like:

**https://player.vimeo.com/external/265193137.source.mp4?s=6...2&oauth2_token_id=1...2**

Here is the expected url:

**https://player.vimeo.com/external/265193137.hd.mp4?s=b...5&profile_id=ABC&oauth2_token_id=1...2**

As you can see, the first url has the word **source.mp4** instead of **hd.mp4**, and it's missing the **profile_id**

Note: i never queried for the source file, just the "link_secure" to the files json array of a video, using a simple restful get

ie: **GET videos/ID?fields=files**

Any help or guidance is much appreciated

Comment: Does this occur with specific videos, or with all of your videos? Has the video finished transcoding?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This happens with all my videos. I believe it's happening when the transcoding hasn't finished yet but it's still sending files information on incomplete files, maybe?